# How does python lambda handle not declared symbols?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, closures

I have a simple module like this:

```py
CMD_MAP = {
    "action": handler
}

def handler(x):
    print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CMD_MAP["action"]("hello")
```

When trying to run/import it, it throws a

```
  File ".../example.py", line 2, in <module>
    "action": handler
NameError: name 'handler' is not defined
```

However, when I change the `CMD_MAP` to :

```py
CMD_MAP = {
    "action": lambda x: handler(x)
}
```

it works without issues. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Everytime you put parens in front of a name you are calling that name. Even if you defined `handler` before `CMD_MAP`, it will not work as expected because the "action" key would hold `None` (the `handler` function has no `return`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body of the lambda isn't evaluated until the lambda is called.  In your first example, you try to call `handler` before it's been defined, so you get an error.  In your second example, `handler` gets called after it's been defined, so it's fine.

Comment: worth mentioning that the first example is a mistake anyway, it should be `"action": handler` not `"action": handler(x)` to be equivalent to the lambda.

Comment: @Dan, yep - shody copying on my part, thanks for pointing it out